# MongooseError: Operation 'fruits.insertOne()' buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, localhost

I wanted to create a collection inside of my fruitsDB database and add a document with Mongoose:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27000/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty solid as a fruit."
})

fruit.save();
```

I started MongoDB community server with the `sudo mongod --port 27000 --dbpath /var/lib/mongo` command, then `nodemon`.
When I query the list of existing databases in the Mongo shell with the show dbs command, the new fruitsDB database isn't listed and I get this error message through nodemon:

```bash
MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/work/Documents/programming/projects/html-css-js/fruits-project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:153:23)

    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)

    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

MongoDB version: 4.4.4

Mongoose version: 6.7.2

Node.js version: 18.12.0

nodemon version: 2.0.20

OS: Linux (Fedora 37 Workstation)

I tried running Mongo server on different ports (including 27017).
Then looked at other related questions here and on MongoDB forum but none of these solved my problem.
How can I solve this problem and add documents to the fruitsDB using Node.js and Mongoose?

Comment: `A Mongoose model doesn't have an insertOne method. Use the create method instead:`

Comment: @HemantSoni what should I change in the code? I can't see any insertOne method. (Sorry I'm a beginner in Mongoose)

Comment: answer is already there @Thomas `const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty solid as a fruit."
})

fruit.save();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following a tutorial, you will likely encounter deprecations. The code below is working for me as of today.

```js
// require mongoose package
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
 
async function main() {
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/FruitsDB');
 
  const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
  });
 
  const Fruit = mongoose.model('Fruit', fruitSchema);
 
  const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: 'Apple',
    rating: 7,
    review: 'Pretty solid as a fruit.'
  });
 
  await fruit.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

remove **{ useNewUrlParser: true }** this code will work